# Powershell script to get only specific Fields in an azure webapp

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azureportal, azure-webapps

Please assist with getting only specific Fields in an azure webapp as below from the SUBSCRIPTION:
App Service Name
Resource Group Name
App Service Plan Name
App Service Plan RG
App service plan SKU
Is auto-scaling configured on app service
Is private endpoint configured on app service
Name of private endpoint
Is vnet integration configured on app service
If vnet is integrated, name of vnet and subnet (vnet/subnet)
Minimum TLS version
Is HTTPS forced?
Custom domains configured on app service

Comment: Do you need details of a single web app or all the webapps?

Comment: All the webapps in the subscription

Answer (score 0):

Run the below query to get the Azure Web App details

```json
Get-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName YourRGName -Name YourWebAppName | ForEach-Object {
    $webapp = Get-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName YourRGName -Name YourWebAppName

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -property @{
      Name = $webapp.Name
      ResourceGroup = $webapp.ResourceGroup
      EnabledHostNames=$webapp.EnabledHostNames
      Http20Enabled = $webapp.siteconfig.Http20Enabled
      MinTlsVersion = $webapp.siteconfig.MinTlsVersion
      AlwaysOn = $webapp.siteconfig.AlwaysOn  
      HttpsOnly = $webapp.HttpsOnly
      ClientAffinityEnabled = $webapp.ClientAffinityEnabled
    } 
}
```

[image]

**OR**

```json
$ResourceGroup="YourRGName"
$WebAppName="YourWebAppName"
az appservice plan show  --resource-group $ResourceGroup --name $WebAppName --query "{resourceGroup:resourceGroup,WebAppName:name,planName:properties.planName,type:type, sku:sku}" && az webapp config show --resource-group $ResourceGroup --name $WebAppName  --query "{minTlsVersion:minTlsVersion}"
```

[image]

**Update**

To get details of All Web Apps in a subscription, run the below query

```json
$AzSubscription = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "*****"
$result=@()  
$webapps = Get-AzWebApp
foreach($webapp in $webapps){
    $Tier = (Get-AzResource -ResourceId $webapp.ServerFarmId).Sku.Tier
    $SKUCapacity = (Get-AzResource -ResourceId $webapp.ServerFarmId).Sku.capacity
 $SKUName = (Get-AzResource -ResourceId $webapp.ServerFarmId).Sku.Name
    $hostName = $webApp | select-object DefaultHostName
    $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $webapp.Name
        State = $webapp.State
        Location = $webapp.Location
        SKUPricingTier = $Tier
        SKUCapacity = $SKUCapacity
SKUName=$SKUName
        AppType = $webapp.Kind
        ResourceGroup = $webapp.ResourceGroup
        Subscription = $AzSubscription.Name
        hostName = $hostName      
        MinTlsVersion = az webapp config show --resource-group $webapp.ResourceGroup --name  $webapp.Name  --query "{minTlsVersion:minTlsVersion}"
        HttpsOnly = $webapp.HttpsOnly
  }
    $result += $obj
}
$result
```

[image]

Comment: To get the details of all WebApps in subscription, remove the ResourceGroup and WebApp name in first query first line.`Get-AzureRMWebApp | ForEach-Object {`

Comment: I'm unable to find the properties for: App Service Name,Resource Group Name,App Service Plan Name,App Service Plan RG,App service plan SKU,Is auto-scaling configured on app service, Is private endpoint configured on app service,Name of private endpoint, Is vnet integration configured on app service,If vnet is integrated, name of vnet and subnet (vnet/subnet)

Comment: You have ResourceGroup,WebAppName,App Service Plan Name , plz check once

Comment: Could you please share your Script, which you have tried from your side?

Comment: Please Check the Update section in the answer.Need to get few more details working on it.

Comment: I'm getting error like this: The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:19 char:25
+         MinTlsVersion = az webapp config show --resource-group $webap ...
+                         ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (az:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Make sure you are running the script in Powershell and not in Bash.

Comment: Yes, I did run the script the Powershell.

Comment: Run this command `az webapp config show --resource-group YourResourceGroupName --name  YourWebAppName  --query "{minTlsVersion:minTlsVersion}"` and check whether you are still getting the error.

Comment: This works fine but I'm still unable to pull other details.

Comment: Ok.remove the line `MinTlsVersion = az webapp config show --resource-group $webapp.ResourceGroup --name  $webapp.Name  --query "{minTlsVersion:minTlsVersion}"` from the script given in answer and run once.

Comment: Still unable to get the Vnet/subnet and Private endpoints the webapp belongs to? Please assist