# Powershell script to get Vnet/subnet,tls version and Private endpoint in an azure webapp

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-webapps

I'm using the below script:

[Powershell script to get only specific Fields in an azure webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73530517/powershell-script-to-get-only-specific-fields-in-an-azure-webapp)
But that appears not to complete the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the script that worked for me.

```
$PrivateEndPoints = Get-AzPrivateEndpoint
$Result=@()
For($I=0;$I -lt $PrivateEndPoints.count;$I++) {
    $PrivateLinkServiceId = $PrivateEndPoints[$I].PrivateLinkServiceConnections.PrivateLinkServiceId
    $SubnetId = $PrivateEndPoints[$I].Subnet.Id
    $WebAppArray = $PrivateEndPoints[$I].PrivateLinkServiceConnections.PrivateLinkServiceId.ToLower() -split "/"
    $SubnetArray = $SubnetId -split "/"
    if(($WebAppArray -like "*Microsoft.Web*") -and ($SubnetId -like "*virtualNetworks*"))
    {           
        For($J=0;$J -lt $SubnetArray.count;$J++){           
            $SubnetNameIndex = $SubnetArray.indexOf("subnets") + 1
            $SubnetName = $SubnetArray[$SubnetNameIndex]
        }
        For($J=0;$J -lt $SubnetArray.count;$J++){           
            $VnetNameIndex = $SubnetArray.indexOf("virtualNetworks") + 1
            $VnetName = $SubnetArray[$VnetNameIndex]
        }
        For($J=0;$J -lt $WebAppArray.count;$J++){           
            $WebAppNameIndex = $WebAppArray.indexOf("sites") + 1
            $WebAppName = $WebAppArray[$WebAppNameIndex]
        }
        $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
            WebAppName = $WebAppName
            PrivateEndpointName = $PrivateEndPoints[$I].Name
            VnetName = $VnetName
            Subnets = $SubnetName
        }
        $Result+=$obj
    }
}
$Result
```

***RESULTS:***
[image]